# Which is the Correct definition of $f_{xy}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, notation

I have seen some authors define $f_{xy}=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}$

as:

$$f_{xy}=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$$

and some authors define in an alternate way. Which is correct?

Comment: Most of the time it makes no difference because of the equality of mixed partials.

Answer (score 2):

The alternate way is correct. The difference between these two traditional notations for partial derivatives is that the subscript notation is **postfix** and the Leibniz notation is **prefix**.

When we use the subscript notation, we write the letter denoting the variable of differentiation **after** the name of the function. That's why, for example, for a function $f(x,y)$ of two variables, its first derivative with respect to $x$ is $f_x$ and its first derivative with respect to $y$ is $f_y$. Therefore, $f_{xy}$ means

> $f_{xy}=(f_x)_y:$ first with respect to $x$ and then with respect to $y$.

When we use the Leibniz notation, we write the differentiation operator **before** the name of the function. That's why, for example, for a function $f(x,y)$ of two variables, its first derivative with respect to $x$ is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and its first derivative with respect to $y$ is $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$. Therefore, $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}$ means

> $\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f\right):$ first with respect to $y$ and then with respect to $x$.

As you can see these are two different things. The same things are the following:
$$f_{xy}=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x} \quad \text{and} \quad f_{yx}=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}.$$

Of course, there's also [Clairaut's Theorem](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_theorem_on_equality_of_mixed_partials) that says that mixed partials are equal when they are continuous. So when we have reasons to assume or know that they are equal, we get careless and write the partials notation in any order we want, and that applies to textbooks too. But this is only valid **after** Clairaut's Theorem has been established, not at all as a definition.